# Pass data from Nova Resource to FormField

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I created a custom Field in Nova and I want to show a list of category in the view and a checkbox will associate with each category.

I already have a recursive array of the category in my resource file but I don't know how to pass it to FormField?

Here is my code:

*Category Resource*

```
$resourceId = $request->route()->parameter('resourceId');
$categories = app(self::$model)->where('id', '!=', $resourceId)->orderBy('position', 'ASC')->get()->toTree();
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `$categories` as field options see docs https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization/fields.html#registering-fields.

`CustomField::make('name custom field')->withMeta(['categories' => $categories]);`

Comment: Thanks, and how can I receive that data from FormField?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still wonders how to get the metadata after passing it to the field in
[Thijs Bouwes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55187641/5182675), it's available under the `field` prop in FormField.